# How to runs testng programmatically?

Tags: testng

I read http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically.
But i want testng read suite and class from testng.xml.
Here is my testng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Suite" verbose="1" >
  <test name="Test" >
    <classes>
       <class name="Test1"/>
       <class name="Test2"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Where are you executing the tests IDE or commandline or build?

Comment: I execute it from a main java class

Answer (score 0):

You would need to download the testng plugin for your IDE.  Once downloaded, you can right click on your xml file and click on Run As -> TestNG suite.  Your testcases need to be structured in the correct way for this to work.  A main method is not required.

Alternately, if just want to use the run properties, for eg, your verbose=1 settings, then you can configure your xml in testng preferences of your project.  It would use that to generate a xml file for the run.

Comment: Thanks, i often do that and now i need it starts from a main class to packed into an application etc...